# auth in kibana cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, high-availability

I was able to setup a kibana 5.1 (with x-pack) cluster with HA. (having several kibana nodes with haproxy setup). I was able to get the cluster running but when I try to log in, it logged me in but in the next request, it will show session timeout and asked me to log in again. I guess it is because the 2nd request hit another node hence it is not logged in. My question is how to config the auth under this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Make your haproxy use sticky sessions?

Comment: yea, that seems the way to go. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moving to an answer since the OP liked it...)

Make your haproxy use sticky sessions.